# Grab variable from for loop based on condition

Tags: javascript

If I have a for loop (example below), how can I grab the variable that's inside based on a condition? What I tried below doesn't seem to work:

```
var b = 0;
for (var a = 0; a < fruit.length; a++) {
  result[a] = function(fruit[a]);           
  if (result[a] <= 1) {
    console.log(fruit[a]);
  }
  b++; 
}

...
```

If `result = 1`, output fruit into the console. The fruit array may look like:

```
('apple', 'orange', 'pear')
```

`result` may look like:

```
(1, 0, 0)
```

So, if apple is put into a function and the result of that function outputs `1` for apple, how can I grab either apple or the index of apple?

Comment: surely your methods identifier is not called "function".

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw, no I just wrote function, the variable array1 is sent to a separate function.

Comment: Take more time and post clean, understandable, valid code. There's way too much missing information here.

Comment: okay, can i see your "separate function" ?

Comment: @squint I made edits, hopefully this is better.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I got it working, not sure why the external function matters in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed it with (Not sure why the function mattered?):**

```
var b = 0;
var gotit=false;
    for(var a = 0; a < fruit.length; a++)
            {
                result[a] = function(fruit[a]);             
            if(result[a] <= 1 && gotit == false)
            {
            gotit=true;
            console.log(fruit[a]);
            }
            b++; 
        }
    }
```